# scss animation works once

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to make a side menu that slides to left and right when you click on it
but it only happens once with animation 
the menu goes to left and right but without any animation

html code

```
<div class="arrow" (click)="gaucheDroite()"
    [ngClass] = "{
            'classgauche' : gauche == 1,
            'classdroite' : gauche == 2
        }">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
<div class="mere" 
[ngClass] = "{
    'classgauche' : gauche == 1,
    'classdroite' : gauche == 2
}">


</div>
```

scss code  animation of the menu

```
.classgauche{
    animation: translatex 1000ms ease-in-out 100ms both;
}
.classdroite{
    animation: translatex 1000ms ease-in-out 100ms reverse both;
}
@keyframes translatex{
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-300px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
.arrow{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    z-index: 11;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 2px 0.5px 3px #b4b4b4;
    //transform: translateX(-300px);
}
```

Angular code on click method

```
  gaucheDroite(){
    //this.gauche = ! this.gauche;
    if(this.gauche == 0 || this.gauche == 1){
      this.gauche =2;
      setTimeout(function() {
          this.gauche =0;
      }, 100);
    }
    else if(this.gauche == 2){
      this.gauche = 1;
      setTimeout(function() {
          this.gauche =0;
      }, 100);
    }
  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do that is use Angular animations. Here you have an example of how to do it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zy3pi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fleft-menu%2Fleft-menu.component.ts